# My bash menu won't return after entering a menu option... here's my code

Tags: bash

Not sure what i'm doing wrong here but I need the menu to loop and only escape when quitting. Iv'e tried lots of options and it just keeps messing up my code and the menu. Any help and / or ideas are greatly appreciated.

```html
#!/bin/bash
# A menu driven shell script sample template
## ----------------------------------
# Step #1: Define variables
# ----------------------------------


EDITOR=vim
PASSWD=/etc/passwd
RED='\033[0;41;30m'
STD='\033[0;0;39m'
COLUMNS=12

# this function is called when Ctrl-C is sent
function trap_ctrlc ()
{
    # perform cleanup here
    echo "Ctrl-C EXITING MENU"

    # exit shell script with error code 2
    # if omitted, shell script will continue execution
    exit 2
}

# initialise trap to call trap_ctrlc function
# when signal 2 (SIGINT) is received
trap "trap_ctrlc" 2

# function to display menus
show_menus() {
    clear
 echo -e " \e[35m"
 cat << "EOF"
    /\   |  __ \ / ____| |  | | | |    |_   _| \ | | |  | \ \ / / |__   __/ __ \ / __ \| |     / ____|
   /  \  | |__) | |    | |__| | | |      | | |  \| | |  | |\ V /     | | | |  | | |  | | |    | (___
  / /\ \ |  _  /| |    |  __  | | |      | | | . ` | |  | | > <      | | | |  | | |  | | |     \___ \
 / ____ \| | \ \| |____| |  | | | |____ _| |_| |\  | |__| |/ . \     | | | |__| | |__| | |____ ____) |
/_/    \_\_|  \_\\_____|_|  |_| |______|_____|_| \_|\____//_/ \_\    |_|  \____/ \____/|______|_____/
EOF
 echo
 echo -e "\e[1m\e[31mTools Version v.1.4.1 \e[0m" # Tools Version
 echo -e "\e[35m \e[1m"
    echo "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
    echo -e "\e[1m\e[36mBash Version | $BASH_VERSION"
    now=$(date +"%r")
    echo -e "\e[36m\e[1mCurrent Time | $now"
    echo -e "\e[35m\e[1m+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
 echo -e "\e[35m \e[1m"
    # UNDERLINE
    echo -e "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
    echo -e "\e[40;38;5;82m A R C H \e[30;48;5;82m T O O L S  M E N U \e[0m"
    echo -e "\e[35m\e[1m+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
 echo -e "\e[35m \e[1m"
    echo '  '"1. Calendar"
    echo '  '"2. Speedtest"
    echo '  '"3. List Hardware (lshwd)"
    echo '  '"4. Kernel Version"
    echo '  '"5. Free Memory"
    echo '  '"6. System Startup Time"
    echo '  '"7. Package Manager (Pamac Update)"
    echo '  '"8. Package Manager (Yay Update)"
    echo '  '"9. List Packages (Yaourt)"
 echo '  '"10. SSH Config"
 echo '  '"11. NGINX Config"
 echo '  '"12. Apache Config (httpd)"
 echo '  '"13. PHP Config (php.ini)"
 echo '  '"14. PHP-FPM (php.fpm.conf)"
 echo '  '"15. Samba Config (smb.conf)"
 echo '  '"16. Squid Config (squid.conf)"
 echo '  '"17. Privoxy Config"
 echo '  '"18. Display Network Config"
    echo '  '"19. Get LAN IP"
    echo '  '"20. UpdateDB"
    echo '  '"21. Exit"
}

# read input from the keyboard and take a action
# invoke the one() when the user select 1 from the menu option.
# invoke the two() when the user select 2 from the menu option.
# Exit when user the user select 3 form the menu option.
read_options(){
    local choice
    read -p "Enter choice [ 1 - 21] " choice
    case $choice in
        1) exec cal ; break ;;
        2) exec speedtest-cli ; break ;;
        3) exec lshwd ; break ;;
        4) exec uname -r ; break ;;
        5) exec free -m ; break ;;
        6) exec systemd-analyze ;;
        7) exec pamac update ;;
        8) exec yay ;;
        9) exec yaourt -Q ;;
  10) exec sudo xed /etc/ssh/sshd_config ;;
  11) exec sudo xed /etc/nginx/nginx.conf ;;
  12) exec sudo xed /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf ;;
  13) exec sudo xed /etc/php/php.ini ;;
  14) exec sudo xed /etc/php/php-fpm.conf ;;
  15) exec sudo xed /etc/samba/smb.conf ;;
  16) exec sudo xed /etc/squid/squid.conf ;;
  17) exec sudo xed /etc/privoxy/config ;;
  18) exec netstat -nat ;;
        19) exec wanip ;;
        20) exec sudo updatedb ;;
        21) exit 0 ;;
        *) echo -e "${RED}Error... Invalid option${STD}" && sleep 2 ;;
    esac
}

# -----------------------------------
# Step #4: Main logic - infinite loop
# ------------------------------------
while : ; do
 clear

    show_menus
    read_options
return
done
```

Not sure what i'm doing wrong here but I need the menu to loop and only escape when quitting. Iv'e tried lots of options and it just keeps messing up my code and the menu. Any help and / or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any reason you're not using the built-in `select` command?

Comment: Your last paragraph is just repeating what you said at the top? Are you just trying to get around SO's requirement to describe the problem more completely? It would be better if you actually gave a more detailed explanation of the problem. What is it doing instead of what you want?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `read_options()` uses `exec` to run the program that's selected. The `exec` command replaces the shell process with the program you specify, so nothing else in the shell script runs after that. You should just execute the commands normally, without using `exec`.

Also, you shouldn't use `break`, as that terminates the `while` loop.

So your `case` statement should look like:

```
case $choice in
    1) cal ;;
    2) speedtest-cli ;;
    3) lshwd ;;
    ...
    21) exit 0 ;;
    *) echo -e "${RED}Error... Invalid option${STD}" && sleep 2 ;;
esac
```